# How to display custom field from a gallery thumbnail?

Tags: php, custom-field

I create a custom field to a image gallery called **views**

[image]

My problem is how can I retrieve the field in my template gallery? See img, I'd like to display **views** below caption where the red arrow is pointing.

[image]

Any suggestions?

Comment: More information would be needed.  Do you know what template is being used?  what did you use to make the custom field?  What have you tried?

Comment: I'm using the default WP gallery template

Answer (score 0):

if your field saved as post_meta, in your page, you can retrieve it using below the code

```
<?php $views = get_post_meta( $current_post_id, 'views', true ); ?>
```

then display it using using `<?php echo $view; ?>`

Comment: Please **[edit] your answer**, and add an explanation: **why** could that solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for your reply Mahmoud!

this How I'm trying to display it!

```
add_filter( 'use_default_gallery_style', 'mysimplefunction' );
function mysimplefunction(){
$views = get_post_meta( $current_post_id, 'views', true );
      echo '<h1>' . $views . '</h1>';
}
```

As I say I'd like it display below my gallery thumbnail ! should I use different fucntion?